# how to prepare `bias` vector in tensor2tensor?

Tags: tensorflow, tensor2tensor

I am having problem understanding how `bias` works in `tensor2tensor`, specially in `multihead_attention` or `dot_product_attention`. I want to use it as a library for my problem.

Lets say I have an input tensor, `T` with dimension, `(batch, max_input_length, hidden_unit)` for a batch of sentences `S`. And I also have a tensor, `sequence_length` whose dimension is `(batch)` mentioning the length of the each sentences in `S`. Now how can I prepare the `bias` vector for this `input`?

I want to calculate the `bias` vector for `self_attention` that means when `q`, `k`, `v` is same.

Another thing,
 What happens to the `bias` if `q` is different and `k`, `v` is same? This is sort of `cross_attention`. I think in that case we have to calculate the bias vector for `k`. But I'm not sure.